# Install Symbian .sis file programmatically using Java ME

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, symbian

I would like to start the installation of sis file through my Java ME application on device.

I know that if I was using Symbian I could use the RSWInstLauncher like http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/SW_Installer_Launcher_API.

Can anyone tell me how I can do a similar thing using Java ME ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a platformrequest with an http url for the SIS-file would work best. Maybe a file: URL could work too.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, however, it prompts the user with the normal install messages.  Have you any idea how I might be able to make the install silent?  Thanks.

Comment: There is no standardized J2ME APIs for installing SIS-files. 
The point is that Symbian doesn't want you to be able to install files silently. It's bad manners not to inform the user about these things. IF you need to install a SIS/JAR combo it's probably better to let the native app install the java app.